# ¿Cómo seleccionar elementos anidados específicos en el DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom

/*¿Cuál es la mejor forma de seleccionar y manipular elementos anidados dentro del DOM utilizando JavaScript? Por ejemplo, si tengo la siguiente estructura HTML:*/

```
<div id="contenedor-padre">
  <div class="elemento">
    <p>Texto 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="elemento">
    <p>Texto 2</p>
    <div class="elemento-hijo">
      <p>Texto 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

¿Cómo puedo seleccionar y trabajar con el párrafo dentro del segundo elemento con la clase "elemento-hijo" utilizando JavaScript? Aprecio cualquier ayuda que puedan proporcionar. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Te recomiendo leer como usar [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). Intentalo y si tenes algun problema, presiona [edit] y actualiza tu pregunta incluyendo el código que desarrollaste.

Answer (score 0):

de esta forma puedes seleccionar el segundo elemento de la clase `elemento-hijo`

```javascript
let elementoHijo = document.querySelector('#contenedor-padre .elemento:nth-child(2) .elemento-hijo p');
```

Te recomiendo leer sobre querySelector